# How do I use the vue-resource plugin to delete an object on demand?

Tags: vue.js

Using the [vue-resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) plugin, it has an example like this:

```
new Vue({

    ready: function() {

      var resource = this.$resource('someItem{/id}');

      // delete item
      resource.delete({id: 1}).then(function (response) {
          // handle success
      }, function (response) {
          // handle error
      });

    }

})
```

I am somewhat confused that this is under the `ready` property since it suggests it runs and deletes something as soon as the component loads. How do I actually use that `resource.delete` function from clicking an element? For example, I have this:

`<div @click="deleteReward(reward)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right"></div>`

which is currently calling this:

```
 deleteReward(reward) {
        this.rewards.$remove(reward);
        this.$http.delete('api/reward/' + reward.id).then(function (response) {
            console.log('deleted ' + reward.name);
        });
    },
```

But my understanding is that I should somehow be able to call `resource.delete` instead and not have to specify the URL and method explicitly. Am I wrong in that assumption?

What I want is to do something like `@click="reward.delete()"` and have it know to call the `resource.delete` automatically and have `resource.delete` accept the reward object as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    resource: null
  },

  ready: function() {
    this.resource = this.$resource('api/reward{/id}')
  },

  methods: {
    deleteReward(reward) {
      this.resource.delete({id:reward.id}).then(function (response) {
        console.log('deleted ' + reward.name)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

And then:

```
<div @click="deleteReward(reward)"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, still wrapping my head around Vue and all its concepts, this is obvious in hindsight. This worked.